# How to install JavaPackage on ubuntu

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I came across a debian application by the name JavaPackage which can create a debian installation file (.deb) form a java binary (.tar.gz) which you can then install using dpkg -i application_name.deb. With Ubuntu being a debian-based linux distribution, it is possible that it can be installed on ubuntu as well.

How do I go about installing it on Ubuntu/Kubuntu 16.04.2 LTS?

Comment: There is a package `java-package` in the official Ubuntu package repositories...

Comment: Yes you can install it on Ubuntu as well. Being Debian based, Ubuntu uses the same package system and supports deb packages. dpkg is also one of the core applications in Ubuntu, so it will be no problem.

Comment: Thanks @arkascha. So this means that I do not have to add any repository to install it

Comment: @arkascha I did specify, 16.04.2 LTS

Comment: Looks like you need the multiverse repository. A simple google search would have shown you: http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=java-package

Comment: also run `update-alternatives --list java` because you can install many jvms/java versions, side by side

Answer (score 1, accepted):

java-package is available in the official ubuntu repositories. All you need to do is update the repository with the latest version then install it as shown below:

```
    sudo apt-get update
    sudo apt-get install java-package
```